InvalidParameterException: Found negative value for salt or password verifier
I trying to imlement the device tracking login but confirmDevice command is giving ingative salt or password verifire always.Some time it also show invalid device key.
error is error: InvalidParameterException: Found negative value for salt or password verifier.
export async function authenticateUser(
email: string,
password: string,
code?: string
): Promise\<IResponseSignIn\> {
try {
        const cognitoClient = new CognitoIdentityProvider({
        region: process.env.POOL_REGION,
        credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWSAccessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWSSecretAccessKey,
        },
        });
        //calculate srp
        const userPoolId = process.env.USER_POOL_ID.split("\_")\[1\];
        const srp = new SRPClient(userPoolId);
        const SRP_A = srp.calculateA();
        const device = new DeviceHelper("", "");
        // const srp_A = device.srpa();
        const secret_hash = calculateSecretHash(process.env.CLIENT_ID, email);

        const params: InitiateAuthCommandInput = {
            AuthFlow: AuthFlowType.USER_SRP_AUTH,
            AuthParameters: {
            USERNAME: email,
            SRP_A: SRP_A,
        },
        ClientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        };
        const authCommand = new InitiateAuthCommand(params);
        const authResponse = await cognitoClient.send(authCommand);
      
        if (authResponse.ChallengeName === "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED") {
            const challengeParams: RespondToAuthChallengeCommandInput = {
                ChallengeName: "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED",
                ClientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
                ChallengeResponses: {
                USERNAME: email,
                NEW_PASSWORD: password,
            },
            Session: authResponse.Session,
        };
        const challengeCommand = new RespondToAuthChallengeCommand(
        challengeParams
        );
        const challengeResponse = await cognitoClient.send(challengeCommand);
        return {
            access_token: challengeResponse.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken,
            refresh_token: authResponse.AuthenticationResult.RefreshToken,
            };
        } 
        else if (authResponse.ChallengeName === "SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA") {
            const challengeResponse = await handleSoftwareTokenMfa(
            code,
            email,
            authResponse.Session,
            secret_hash
            );
        return {
            access_token: challengeResponse.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken,
            refresh_token: challengeResponse.AuthenticationResult.RefreshToken,
        };
        } else if (authResponse.ChallengeName === "PASSWORD_VERIFIER") {
            const salt = authResponse.ChallengeParameters.SALT;
            const userIdForSrp = authResponse.ChallengeParameters.USER_ID_FOR_SRP;
            const srp_b = authResponse.ChallengeParameters.SRP_B;
            const secretBlock = authResponse.ChallengeParameters.SECRET_BLOCK;
            const username = authResponse.ChallengeParameters.USERNAME;
            const hkdf = srp.getPasswordAuthenticationKey(
            userIdForSrp,
            password,
            srp_b,
            salt
            );
            const dateNow = getNowString();
            const signatureString = calculateSignature(
            hkdf,
            userPoolId,
            userIdForSrp,
            secretBlock,
            dateNow
            );
        const challengeParams: RespondToAuthChallengeCommandInput = {
            ChallengeName: "PASSWORD_VERIFIER",
            ClientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
            ChallengeResponses: {
                PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE: signatureString,
                PASSWORD_CLAIM_SECRET_BLOCK: secretBlock,
                TIMESTAMP: dateNow,
                USERNAME: username,
                SECRET_HASH: secret_hash,
            },
            Session: authResponse.Session,
        };

      const challengeCommand = new RespondToAuthChallengeCommand(
        challengeParams
      );
      const challengeResponsePasswordVerifier = await cognitoClient.send(
        challengeCommand
      );
      let challengeResponse;
      if (
        challengeResponsePasswordVerifier.ChallengeName === "SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA"
      ) {
        challengeResponse = await handleSoftwareTokenMfa(
          code,
          email,
          challengeResponsePasswordVerifier.Session,
          secret_hash
        );
      }
      const device_key =
        challengeResponse.AuthenticationResult.NewDeviceMetadata.DeviceKey;
      const access_token = challengeResponse.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken;
      const device_group_key =
        challengeResponse.AuthenticationResult.NewDeviceMetadata.DeviceGroupKey;
    
      const deviceHelper = new DeviceHelper(device_key, device_group_key);
      const verifierConfig = deviceHelper.passwordVerifierConfig(username);
      // register a device
      const isDevice = await handleConfirmDevice(
        access_token,
        device_key,
        `${username}${device_key}`,
        verifierConfig.salt,
        verifierConfig.passwordVerifier
      );
      if (isDevice) {
        await handleUpdateDeviceStatus(access_token, device_key, "remembered");
      }
      return {
        access_token: challengeResponse.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken,
        refresh_token: challengeResponse.AuthenticationResult.RefreshToken,
      };
    }
}

I am expecting it should return true and then updateDeviceStatus will run with device_key set to "remembered"
